# VIM: how do I get close parenthesis aligned with block like close brace does?

Tags: vim, auto-indent

in vim
when you close the brace, it automatically aligned with the block head of the opening brace. like this:

```
f() {
    ...
}
```

how do I get closing parenthesis automatically moved and aligned the same way:

```
f (
   int i,
   ...
) {
```

At the moment, I can only get it aligned by use alignment command. e.g ==, without the command, it looks like this:

```
f (
    int i,
    ...
    ) {
```

i.e. an extra indent from where it is supposed to be aligned.

how do I fix this problem and make it work just like a closing brace?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the value of [`'indentexpr'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27indentexpr%27).

If it's set (e.g. to `GetJavaIndent()`), you should look into fixing the corresponding function. No generic advice can be given here.

If `'indentexpr'` is not set, you're using `'cindent'`, the behaviour of which can be affected with [`'cinoptions'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cinoptions%27). The option you're looking for is `m1`. So just add this to your `vimrc`, and you should be set: `set cinoptions=m1` (maybe wrap it into `autocmd` or something so that it will only affect specific filetypes.)